# How can I use preg_match_all() to convert a string with 2 delimiters into an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, associative-array, preg-match-all

I rarely uses regular expressions, but think I might have a situation that calls for them nicely (using preg_match_all).

Input:

```
10 - RIGHT SIDE|Validated,11 - ENTRY DOOR|Validated,20 - ENTRY DOOR|Not Validated
```

I am attempting to split each array index on the comma, and ideally, the key would be the text before the pipe, and the value the text after the pipe in each split.

Expected output:

```
array(0): key(10 - RIGHT SIDE) => value(Validated)
array(1): key(11 - ENTRY DOOR) => value(Validated)
array(2): key(20 - ENTRY DOOR) => value(Not Validated)
```

This will always be in a single long string of text.

Here is what I tried:

```
preg_match_all('/([^|]*?):([^,]*),?/', $strPoints, $arrPoints);
$out = array_combine($arrPoints[1], $arrPoints[2]);
```

Which gave me something close (truncated the output):

```
Array
(
    [29 - Em Exit] =>  ENTERTAINMENT AREA|Not Validated
    [35 - Em Exit] =>  ENTERTAINMENT AREA|Validated
    [36 - Em Exit] =>  ENTERTAINMENT AREA|Validated
)
```

Comment: Your regex looks for a `:` colon, while your sample uses `|` pipes as delimiters. (How and where from your final output came to be isn't very clear..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

You don't really need a regex for this. First just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string into an array by a comma. So that you have an array, e.g.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10 - RIGHT SIDE|Validated
    [1] => 11 - ENTRY DOOR|Validated
    [2] => 20 - ENTRY DOOR|Not Validated
)
```

After this you go through each array element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and explode it again, but this time by a pipe. Then you will end up with this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10 - RIGHT SIDE
            [1] => Validated
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11 - ENTRY DOOR
            [1] => Validated
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20 - ENTRY DOOR
            [1] => Not Validated
        )

)
```

And at the end you can simply use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to use the 0 column as key and 1 as value.

So the full code would look something like this:

```
<?php

    $str = "10 - RIGHT SIDE|Validated,11 - ENTRY DOOR|Validated,20 - ENTRY DOOR|Not Validated";

    $arr = array_column(array_map(function($v){
        return explode("|", $v);
    }, explode(",", $str)), 1, 0);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [10 - RIGHT SIDE] => Validated
    [11 - ENTRY DOOR] => Validated
    [20 - ENTRY DOOR] => Not Validated
)
```

Comment: I get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column() EDIT: looks like i'll be updated php tonight

Comment: @SourceMatters You then probably have PHP version (`echo phpversion();`) under <5.5. So just replace the code with this: `$arr = array_map(function($v){
  return explode("|", $v);
 }, explode(",", $str));
 
 $arr = array_combine(
  array_map(function($v){
   return $v[0];
  }, $arr),
  array_map(function($v){
   return $v[1];
  }, $arr)
 );`

Comment: The output does look right with that, but I get a Notice: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on this line: return $v[1]; }, $arrPoints

Comment: @SourceMatters You probably use a different string, than you show us here! Which means you don't have equal amount of keys and values. Because I can't reproduce it. My code works fine: http://3v4l.org/HcNPO

Comment: Ahhh I think I know why - my string ends in a comma, so it's probably looking for something after it, but it's empty. I'm going to try to "pop" it off the end of the array before doing the array_combine thing. EDIT: Yep! That did the trick!

Comment: @SourceMatters Instead of using the plain `$str` in my code. Wrap an `trim()` call around it, e.g. `trim($str, ",")` and then use it in my code